# Who calls the copy constructor when passing by value?

Tags: c++

Well I have a small question to solve a matter of mine (and maybe some others ^^). So let's assume the following in C++ :

```
class A {
  public:
    A() { }
    A(const A& src) { }
};

class B {
  public:
    B() { }
    void foo(A valuePassing) { }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A passed;
    B obj;

    obj.foo(passed);        

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this code, who is responsible of calling `A`'s `copy constructor`? The question could be generalized : when passing by value, who is responsible of the copy of the variable, the caller or the callee? In that specific case, will `B` call the copy constructor when receiving the var or is it `main()` which will call it and send the copy over to `B`'s method?

My first thought is that, to maintain the protection induced by C++ accesibilities, it should be the caller doing the copy job. But I need to be sure of it. And is it common to every compiler (don't see why not but differences between compilers are sometimes so weird)? Namely VC++ and gcc.

Thanks in advance for your answers ;)

Edit:
If anyone wonders, this is about implementing the [Pass Key pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324898/can-we-increase-the-re-usability-of-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern) created by [Georg Fritzsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168225/georg-fritzsche). Indeed, as some stated, making it non-copyable is a good idea to prevent not too smart developers from making a function that gives the key to anyone from the class that is granted the key. But making it non-copyable also prevents standard value argument passing (at least it should, I have found out that Visual C++ compiler does not follow the standard and is actually ok with that...)

My idea to solve the problem is to create a base `PassKey` class that has protected copy constructor and assignment operator. Then every `PassKey` classes will inherit from this one. Then the function that require the key to be used ask as first parameter the key by **value**. This way even if a smartass developer do the previously mentioned function and gives a reference to the key, the external class that will try to use it won't be able to because it needs access to the key's `copy constructor` which is accessible only to the protected and granted classes.

Was I clear enough or do that need some clarification? :S

Comment: Would the difference have any observable effect?  Surely all that matters is that at some point, a copy gets made.

Comment: what do you mean by "who"? The compiler inserts a call to the copy constructor in the context of `main`. Arguments have to be initialized before the function is invoked.

Comment: I suppose the calling code *caused* the copy to occur by calling the function and passing `passed`, but asking what is "responsible" for it doesn't really make sense. If anything, the initialization of the argument is responsible for it.

Comment: The question is complicated by inlining, in this specific code there might not even _be_ a "call" to `B::foo`. The copy might still happen, but how do you say "who" did it, if the function is inlined?

Comment: neither the caller nor the calle. The compiler. All praise the compiler

Comment: By who is responsible I meant who called it of course. I thought it to be obvious sorry :S Should I change the title? What I mean is if the copy constructor is protected it can still be called by children or friends. But in the case of passing the class by value, which results in a copy, who calls the constructor? I believe that would be the caller but I'm not sure as I said. Still some people seem to agree ^^ So I'll try. @OliCharlesworth That makes a HUGE difference, specifically because of the copy constructor accessibility ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.foo(passed);` will result in the following sequence of steps, generated by a compiler:

1. Put `obj`'s pointer onto stack frame (the `this` parameter)
2. Create a `temp` variable (this is where the copy constructor is being called)
3. Put that `temp` onto stack frame
4. Make a call to `foo()`
5. Once returned from the function - clear up the stack (this is where the destructor is called)

Comment: Is this guaranteed by the C++ standard?

Comment: Not in standard, this is the "usual" implementation

Comment: The creation of the temporary & use of copy-initialization is guaranteed according to the rules in §8.5.3.

Comment: Oh wow thanks @MichaelFoukarakis. You mean that it is guaranteed by the standard that the caller of a function/method will call the copy constructors of the variables sent to the function by value? (in this case main will call the copy constructor of `A` to copy `passed` and give the copy to `B.foo`?)

Comment: In this case, it is. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826934/copy-constructor-needed-with-temp-object) and answers for more information.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Well from what I read on that other topic, VC9 already didn't give a damn about copy-ctors accessibility :P Well anyway thank you for all the information that really helps, hopefully I can get my rep up and comment on the topic I mentioned in the question if I can make the PassKey pattern fully protected.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it is understandable and because @MichaelFoukarakis actually found a reference to this in the standard, so this is now something guaranteed. Thanks everyone for all the tips! Oh also I just realized in your answer YePhIcK, if I understand correctly, it is also the caller's scope that calls the destructor right?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'll answer as general as I am able.

The short answer is that it is your compiler's job to call the constructor. It will as far as I know also be constructed by the caller. Exactly how this is done, however, may depend on the calling convention you are using.

There exists a number of calling conventions, one compiler may support more than one, see for instance [this page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx). And different architectures may demand a specific convention.

For x86, one calling convention would be like YePhIck answered, whilst on for instance on an ARM platform, the address would be placed directly in a register before the branch to the function. And not pushed to the stack (unless you have more than 4 parameters).

Can it ever be the callee's responsibility to copy the object? I'm not aware of such a calling convention, but it might exist.

Comment: Yeah just checked I use the cdecl as my calling convention (I remember configuring that because I didn't want to use the default VC++ calling convention because of a particular feature, can't remember which). What matters is that it is the caller that calls the copy constructor so thanks ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter?

Comment: Ah, just read your edit, so the question is really: Will this protected constructor be in scope when function X is called...

Comment: Yes, the intent being that the constructor hopefully is not called by the callee function since that would completely break the security of the PassKey pattern ;) But if @MichaelFoukarakis confirms that it is part of the standard then the PassKey would not only be more human-readable than the Attorney-Client idiom but also a bit more safe!

Comment: Wanted to vote up but my rep doesn't allow it =/ Why participating doesn't count toward rep :( Yeah well anyway, I vote you up in comments :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, how class B can invoke a function by itself? You have just two places for copy constructor calling: main() and foo(). And I can't see any calls from foo, so the answer is obvious.
And don't forget about return type of foo().

Comment: Woops sorry about foo's type, was a sample :S Well since the call is not explicit I just wanted to be sure. The call is done implicitly during the execution of the foo method ;)