# Aren't template class member functions compiled at instantiation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I found a strange issue when porting my code from Visual Studio to gcc. The following code compiles fine in Visual Studio, but results in an error in gcc.

```
namespace Baz
{
   template <class T>
   class Foo
   {
   public:
      void Bar()
      {
         Baz::Print();
      }
   }; 

   void Print() { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; }
}

int main()
{
   Baz::Foo<int> foo;
   foo.Bar();

   return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that this should compile OK, as the class shouldn't be compiled until the template is instantiated (which is after Print() is defined). However, gcc reports the following:

> t.cpp: In member function 'void Baz::Foo::Bar()':
>   Line 8: error: 'Print' is not a member of 'Baz'

Who's right? And if gcc is right, why?

Comment: Is this the full code? I think you are missing a semicolon after the class declaration

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. This would be correct with a semicolon there.

Comment: I ran into a similar situation when testing a compiler update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615660/why-this-warning-from-ibm-xl-c-c-compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc is right. It is because `Baz` is a namespace and namespaces are parsed top to bottom, so the declaration of `Baz::Print` is not visible from inside `Foo` (since it is beneath it).

When the template is instantiated, only names visible from the template definition are considered, not counting Koenig lookup (which wouldn't change anything in your case).

If `Baz` were a struct or class, your code would work, since these are parsed in two phases (first declarations, then bodies), so anything declared in a struct or class is visible inside eg. member functions, regardles of their order in the source file.

You can make it work by declaring `Baz::Print` before `Foo`.

Quoting the standard:

### 14.6.3 Non-dependent names

Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the usual name lookup and bound at the
point they are used.

### 14.6.4 Dependent name resolution

In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:

- Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
- Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both 
  from the instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context.

(end quotation)

When `Print` is nondependent (as it is now), it wouldn't be found since it is looked up before its declaration (in the template definition context). If it were dependent, it wouldn't be the first case (same as when nondependent), and `Baz` is not associated with int (the template parameter) in any way, so it wouldn't be searched according to the second case either.

Comment: Also...

14.6.4.2 For a function call that depends on a template parameter, if the function name is an unqualified-id or if the function is called using operator notation, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that (1) For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations from the template definition context are found. (2) For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

Comment: @jpalececk, thanks for the detailed answer with all edge cases (specifically with regards to unqualified vs qualified names). This was a very interesting situation.

Comment: @shi: `Baz::Print` is a qualified name, not an unqualified one.

Answer (score 9):

gcc is right. Templates are compiled in two stages: once when they are parsed, and once when they are instantiated.

At parse time, anything that does NOT depend on the template parameters is checked, so in this case `Baz::Print` is looked up, and found not to have been declared, so this is an error.

If the call had been `T().Print()` or something else that depended on the type `T` then the lookup would be delayed until instantiation time (or least partially delayed --- see below.)

Qualified names like Baz::Print are always looked up at definition time unless the qualification itself depends on the template parameter (e.g. `T::Print`), though overload resolution is deferred to instantiation time. This means that you cannot add to the overload set for qualified names after the template has been declared.

Unqualified names such as just `Print` are looked up at instantiation time if any of the function arguments depend on a template parameter. So `Print(T())` would be looked up at instantiation time, whilst `Baz::Print(T())` is not. It's worth noting that the instantiation-time lookup is restricted to those names visible at the point of declaration and those found through ADL, so for `Foo<int>`, even a plain `Print(T())` should not find `Baz::Print` if it was declared after the template (like in the example).

To make the example code work, either define `Foo<T>::Bar` after the definition of `Print`, or forward-declare `Print` before the definition of `Foo`.

Comment: Strange, it seems to be true here...

http://codepad.org/eIHsc8Lu

Could this be the vararg at fault? (Because in such a situation, the type is irrelevant.)

Comment: @shi: Your samples are not qualifying the calls with the namespace (`Baz::...`).

Comment: @Shirik: IMHO this is nonstandard behaviour. See the quotation of the standard I added to my reply.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to include points from these comments.